# How do you create color scales?

Tags: color, palette

I know that you can tint a color to white and shade it to black but this is not always good enough to me as it can produce very desaturated results.

Also will you take in consideration to have a color scale from red to orange to yellow for instance? It means that the hue of the color will change but as we perceive these colors darker or lighter it kinda makes sense to me.

Since I'm building an app that allows exactly that I'm looking for references regarding this.

Comment: Very interesting approach. You might gain some inspiration (especially for your UI look) from [a long list of color generator sites](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/63524/23061)

Comment: Color splines have been used for ages in the VFX industry. Nothing new here except that your spline is offcourse somehow fixed.

Comment: sorry but what kind of feedback do you want? Aside from just promoting your app, general feedback is a bit too broad for GD.SE.

Comment: @luciano I need to understand if the app can be useful to generate a color scales. I'm using it but I'm obviously biased. Plus the other feedback about the UI and usability in general are precious to me. For instance I'm going to change the position of the cookie banner and smooth down the experience of selecting s color.

Comment: If you want feedback about the UI please be specific, there are guidelines check here https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/682/2611. GD.SE is not a forum but a Q&A site, so feedback questions are sometimes closed as off-topic.

Comment: Thanks Luciano, you're totally right. I edited the post with some more direct questions.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/58735/how-can-i-make-the-color-white-look-as-white-as-possible/58737#58737 and https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/74359/gradient-white-mark-optical-illusion/81181#81181 P.S. This question is not offtopic.

Comment: Thanks Rafael, the question was off topic because I was asking generic feedback about the app I built. The links you sent confirm I'm applying he right principles as I let the user adjust the hue of the gradient on which pick the colors. And I let the user tune a logarithmic progression with splines

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I intentionally did not look at the intro (as I expect many users won't).*

Things I noticed are:

1. I expected to be able to click into the main square to change the "square" color
2. The selection of "square" color could be visible at all times to smooth the workflow
3. The swatches could be labeled by more than just the rgb hex code (CMYK, 1-255 etc.)
4. The export button is hidden by the cookie opt-out banner for me.

Overall, it seems like you went for the sleekest look possible, leaving some of the functionality and ease-of-use behind.

As I am not a professional graphic designer, nor a professional painter, I cannot really give any feedback about usefulness of such an app.