# Calculation of RGB colors based on a sample color with darker and lighter variants

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, color-theory, rgb

I have an icon which utilizes 3 variants of the same basic color (at least it seems).

This is the basic color: **#7646be**:

[image]

1st variant (darker version): **#582299**:

[image]

2nd variant (lighter version): **#c4acff**:

[image]

My question is how to get the very same color "variants" for a different color?

For example this is another base color, and I'm looking for the lighter and darker variants for this based on the above sample:

[image]

Comment: 1. Your lighter example has a hue change that does not need to be there.

Comment: 2. Sometimes a change in brightness produces an illusion that the hue is not right. Take a look at this: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/58735/how-can-i-make-the-color-white-look-as-white-as-possible/58737#58737

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the same saturation and brightness adjustments to each base hue.

i.e. ...

Leave the `H` number as it is and change the `S` and `B`.... 
Saturation `+7` and Brightness `-15` for darker variant
Saturation `-30` and Brightness `+25` for lighter variant

[image]

Comment: Dark version seems OK, but light version is not for some reason. Can you please double check? In the sample, lighter version changes the Hue value. Shall I change it accordingly?

Comment: @Daniel I did fail to notice that the hue changed for the purple light variant. To be honest, if sticking to this method isn't working, it's best to use it to get close, then if you feel more fine tuning is necessary you need to do that visually. Changing the Hue by 7pts will not make a big difference, but it will make *some* difference.

Comment: @Daniel, you could try using Lab/Hcl instead if you want to be more "scientific" about it, but I agree that in the end finetuning the colors to a pleasing result is not something to be ashamed of. It's not given that a set of tints look "best" if they have the exact same hue and saturation. Sometimes for example it can look good to increase (or decrease) saturation as brightness increases.